# Upload a file from a server to Hdfs in another server

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I want to upload a file from an external Windows server to Hdfs in a different server. Hdfs is part of cloudera docker container in that server.

I connected to the Hdfs from Windows server as below:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://%HDFS_SERVER_IP%:8020");
fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

When I call `fs.copyFromLocalFile(localFilePath, hdfsFilePath);` , it throws below exceptions and it creates the file without any content in Hdfs. :

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/test/test.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:677)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.addBlock(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:485)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2086)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2082)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2080)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:448)
```

And there seems a problem in datanode, the below is copied from its log:

> Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8022. Already tried 0
>   time(s); retry policy is
>   RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000
>   MILLISECONDS)

I formatted the datanodes and restart hdfs but still can't upload the file in this case. Besides other functions such as reading, writing file are working with the configuration and the file can be transferred if the local system and Hdfs are in the same server.

The servers are connected to the proxy server and I configured proxy environment of the docker container of Hdfs. How is the file transferred by using Hdfs Java Api between different servers?

**Update 1:**

hdfs dfsadmin -report :

```
17/04/05 07:14:02 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032
Total Nodes:1
         Node-Id             Node-State Node-Http-Address       Number-of-Running-Containers
quickstart.cloudera:37449               RUNNING quickstart.cloudera:8042                                   0
[root@quickstart conf]# hdfs dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 211243687936 (196.74 GB)
Present Capacity: 78773199014 (73.36 GB)
DFS Remaining: 77924307110 (72.57 GB)
DFS Used: 848891904 (809.57 MB)
DFS Used%: 1.08%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (1):

Name: XXXX:50010 (quickstart.cloudera)
Hostname: quickstart.cloudera
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 211243687936 (196.74 GB)
DFS Used: 848891904 (809.57 MB)
Non DFS Used: 132470488922 (123.37 GB)
DFS Remaining: 77924307110 (72.57 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.40%
DFS Remaining%: 36.89%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 6
Last contact: Wed Apr 05 07:15:00 UTC 2017
```

yarn node -list -all :

```
17/04/05 07:14:02 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032
Total Nodes:1
         Node-Id             Node-State Node-Http-Address       Number-of-Running-Containers
quickstart.cloudera:37449               RUNNING quickstart.cloudera:8042                                   0
```

core-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020</value>
  </property>

  <!-- OOZIE proxy user setting -->
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>

  <!-- HTTPFS proxy user setting -->
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.httpfs.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.httpfs.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>

  <!-- Llama proxy user setting -->
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.llama.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.llama.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>

  <!-- Hue proxy user setting -->
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <!-- Immediately exit safemode as soon as one DataNode checks in.
       On a multi-node cluster, these configurations must be removed.  -->
  <property>
    <name>dfs.safemode.extension</name>
    <value>0</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.safemode.min.datanodes</name>
     <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
     <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.permissions</name>
     <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.safemode.min.datanodes</name>
     <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
     <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
     <value>/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
     <value>/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}/dfs/name</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
     <value>/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}/dfs/namesecondary</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
     <value>/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}/dfs/data</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-bind-host</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:8022</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.https.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50470</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50070</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50010</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.ipc.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50020</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50075</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.https.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50475</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50090</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.https-address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50495</value>
  </property>

  <!-- Impala configuration -->
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.hdfs-blocks-metadata.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.file-block-storage-locations.timeout.millis</name>
    <value>10000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.read.shortcircuit</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.domain.socket.path</name>
    <value>/var/run/hadoop-hdfs/dn._PORT</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Where are you running this code from? It must be on the Windows Server. Also post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: How do you initialize the file system?

Comment: Does the datanode have sufficient space! Add the output of `hdfs dfsadmin -report`, `yarn node -list -all` and the `core-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml` properties.

Comment: @franklinsijo I added the outputs.

Comment: 1) Try to do `netstat -anp` to see which ports are actually being in use (you can `netstat -anp | grep 80` to filter the results a bit). 2) Try disabling the firewall for few minutes and repeat your tests. 3) Instead of host name try to use IP (or at least make sure the host name is being resolved properly with trace route or something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only changed `conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://%HDFS_SERVER_IP%:8020")` to `conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "webhdfs://%HDFS_SERVER_IP%:50070")` and then I succesfully upload the files to the hdfs in the different server. I referred to this [link](http://henning.kropponline.de/2016/02/14/a-secure-hdfs-client-example/).

Answer (score 1):

The **`RPC`** ports are in conflict between the properties `fs.defaultFS` in `core-site.xml` and  `dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address` in `hdfs-site.xml`.

Modify this in `hdfs-site.xml` and restart the services.

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:8020</value>
</property>
```

Comment: I modified and namenode couldn't be initialized. I changed the name of the property as dfs.namenode.rpc-address, and still got same exceptions. org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8020. is still in the log of datanode.

Comment: They are RemoteException same as described in the question and org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8020 in log of the datanode

Comment: Can you replace all the instances of `0.0.0.0` to `quickstart.cloudera`!